# SVG elements list

Tags: css, svg, hover

I'm trying to do something that looks the snippet i added but with svg circles, is it possible that i put my svg circles in a list? i want the box to appear when i hover into my circle

```css
ul#list_of_thrones {
  list-style-type:none;
}
ul#list_of_thrones li{
  position: relative;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
ul#list_of_thrones li > span{
  position: relative;
  display:none;
}
ul#list_of_thrones li:hover > span{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:100px;
  display:block;
  background:red;
  color:white;
  padding:6px;
}

ul#list_of_thrones li:hover > span:after {
 right: 100%;
 top: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-right-color: red;
 border-width: 6px;
 margin-top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list_of_thrones">
  <li>Tyrion<span>Lannister</span></li>
  <li>Loras<span>Tyrell</span></li>
  <li>Gregor<span>Clegane</span></li>
  <li>Brandon<span>Stark</span></li>
  <li>Daenerys<span>Targaryen</span></li>
  <li>Oberyn<span>Martell</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where would you like `your circles` to be? In front of the text, as list-style element?

Comment: @Tymek no i want to put circles instead of the text and when i hover into them the box shows

Comment: @RickHitchcock can do one for me please? because when i do that the circle disappears

Comment: @RickHitchcock im sorry for bothering but here is my code 

<ul id="list_of_thrones">
  <li><svg><circle cx="157" cy="160" class="black-circle"/></svg><span>Tyrell</span></li>
  <li><svg><circle cx="221" cy="70" class="black-circle"/></svg><span>Clegane</span></li>
  <li><svg><circle cx="490" cy="80" class="black-circle"/></svg><span>Stark</span></li>
  <li><svg><circle cx="690" cy="140" class="black-circle"/></svg><span>Targaryen</span></li>
  <li><svg><circle cx="850" cy="185" class="black-circle"/></svg><span>Martell</span></li>
</ul>

it didn't work properly

Comment: Your circles are missing a radius.  Add something like `r="10"` like I did in my Snippet.

Comment: @RickHitchcock they do have a radius but it's in a separate css file

Comment: Hmm, I'd need to see your CSS to understand the problem.

Comment: @RickHitchcock 
https://jsfiddle.net/po8c0LLv/

Comment: Within CSS, `r` needs a unit.  Try `14px`:  https://jsfiddle.net/ksdy8n6d/

Comment: @RickHitchcock okay thank you, but did you notice that the box doesn't appear when i hover into the circle?

Comment: It appears for me, but it's not in the appropriate place.  If it doesn't appear at all for you, what browser are you using?

Comment: @RickHitchcock the problem is that when you hover into the svg viewbox it appears, but i want it to appear when you hover into the circle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136109/discussion-between-rick-hitchcock-and-stephjhonny).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace the text with an SVG circle, and you should get the same functionality using your existing CSS:

```
<li><svg><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/></svg><span>Tyrell</span></li>
```

**Snippet:**

```css
ul#list_of_thrones {
  list-style-type:none;
}
ul#list_of_thrones li{
  position: relative;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
ul#list_of_thrones li > span{
  position: relative;
  display:none;
}
ul#list_of_thrones li:hover > span{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:100px;
  display:block;
  background:red;
  color:white;
  padding:6px;
}

svg {
  height: 1.5em;
}

ul#list_of_thrones li:hover > span:after {
 right: 100%;
 top: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-right-color: red;
 border-width: 6px;
 margin-top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list_of_thrones">
  <li><svg><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/></svg><span>Tyrell</span></li>
  <li><svg><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/></svg><span>Clegane</span></li>
  <li><svg><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/></svg><span>Stark</span></li>
  <li><svg><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/></svg><span>Targaryen</span></li>
  <li><svg><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/></svg><span>Martell</span></li>
</ul>
```